# Can you detect whether an app has been side load via adb?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, sideloading

I want to know if this is possible in android. I want the application to tell me if it was sideloaded via ADB, since I know adb can be used to bypass the package installer name. Is there any method for detection on whether an application was loaded through adb.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's is no **reliable** method to tell what is the origin of given application installed on the device.

Comment: Ok in which case, would you be able to suggest me (if you can) a method in which I can disable in-app purchases if it has been sideloaded.

Comment: Hm, since you cannot tell you are sideloaded or not, how would you like this to work?

Comment: Isn't there some kind of API with the play store server or something to say that this app has been loaded from this store. I mean it doesn't have to be that it detects sideloading but rather it detects that it hasn't been loaded from unapproved stores or anywhere else.

Comment: The key in my answer is the word **reliable**. Not sure what you want to achieve by attempting to detect that - maybe there's much better and more reliable approach for that anyway